# How to enable "Share and organize quick text in folders" via SFDX?

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, quick-text

How do I automate enabling "Share and organize quick text in folders" via the SFDX CLI?

[image]

I've looked and I can't seem to see a feature to enable, and I can't find out how to set this. Because my layout for QuickText includes folders, I can't deploy my scratch org.

Someone on the SFXD Discord server suggested the following:

```json
{
  "edition": "Developer",
  "orgName": "My Scratch Org",
  "settings": {
    "macroSettings": {
      "macrosInFolders": true
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately that doesn't affect the setting I showed above, and my deployment once again fails because it isn't enabled:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the "macroSettings" in your scratch org definition file (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file.htm) you should use the setting "quickTextSettings". Add this and recreate the org - the checkbox will be set.

```
{
  "edition": "Developer",
  "orgName": "My Scratch Org",
  "settings": {
    "quickTextSettings": {
      "quickTextsInFolders": true
    }
  }
}
```

When you struggle to find the name of a setting, just activate it in the org, then retrieve all settings from org and you will find all the activated settings (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_orgsettings.htm). You can retrieve all settings with this package.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Settings</name>
    </types>
    <version>59.0</version>
</Package>
```

Comment: I think this needs some additional supporting details. Where would someone be putting this JSON fragment?

Comment: I'm going to assume you're right and this works now. I have no way of testing as we moved away from Salesforce. Hopefully this can help someone else.